# java.lang.OutMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, csv

tengo un código que sirve para copiar y pegar un archivo .csv en otro archivo .csv

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader reader;
    BufferedWriter writer;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataset = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    int i=1;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./champs.csv"));
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./salida_java.csv", false));
        String line = reader.readLine(); //Asigna una el metodo del reader, leer linea al string
        int j;
        while (line != null)
        {
            ArrayList<String> parsing1 = new ArrayList<String>(); // los elementos de una fila
            String[] row1;
            row1 = line.split(",",-1);
            for(String x : row1)
            {
                if(x.length() > 0 && x.charAt(0) == ',')    //Si el string comienza con , se lo quita
                {
                    if(x.length() > 1) {
                        x = x.substring(1, x.length());
                    }
                }
                parsing1.add(x); //le añade el string al arraylist parsing1
            }
            dataset.add(parsing1); //le añade el string el arraylist de arraylist dataset
            line = reader.readLine(); //lee la siguiente linea
        }

        for(ArrayList a : dataset)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < a.size()-1; j++)
            {
                writer.write(a.get(j).toString());
                writer.write(",");
            }
            writer.write(a.get(j).toString());
            //writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            writer.write("\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

El tema es que para archivos de poco espacio me funciona bien pero en el caso de ponerle un archivo mas grande, por ejemplo en la imagen es de 300 mb me sale ese error. Por lo que he buscado este error se produce cuando no hay espacio suficiente para seguir asignando al objeto, pero no entiendo mas allá como solucionarlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Hay varios problemas que no has tenido en cuenta en tu programa y que están causando ese fallo.

En primer lugar, la memoria asignada a tu programa al ejecutarse en la JVM es limitada. Al ir almacenando el contenido del fichero en una lista de listas de cadenas de texto, estás llenando esa memoria.

Con datos pequeños, va a dar igual porque hay memoria suficiente, pero para grandes cantidades de datos, vas a agotar la memoria asignada por la JVM a tu programa, y en el momento en que se hace un nuevo `split` (que es la llamada que causa que se creen nuevos objetos de tipo `String`, y por tanto la mayoría de las reservas de memoria del programa) el programa llega a su límite y al no poder reservar más memoria, la JVM lanza un `Error`, clase hermana a `Exception`, pero para errores internos de la JVM.

La solución es ejecutar al programa con argumentos para la JVM en relación con una reserva de más memoria. Ejecuta tu programa con el argumento `-Xms<memoria>`, utilizando `M` o `G` para indicar que le número es en Megas o Gigas de memoria RAM. Ten en cuenta que `-Xms` especifica un mínimo de memoria para tu programa, y que la JVM va a intentar dártelo siempre que pueda, pero puede ocurrir que no tenga memoria suficiente para asignar a tu programa, o que pidas algo poco razonable.

Por tanto, esta primera solución no arregla tu problema completamente, ya que aceptaría ficheros de 300M o incluso de 1G o más. Pero imagínate que tienes un *.csv* que ocupa 100G. Dudo que tengas tanta memoria RAM en tu ordenador. Por tanto, no es una solución, es un parche.

Puedes adoptar otro enfoque. En vez de leer el contenido, guardarlo en RAM, y volcarlo luego a otro fichero; puedes leer una línea, hacer el `split`, almacenar solo una línea en RAM, y a continuación volcarla en el nuevo fichero, es decir, no leerlo completo, sino línea por línea ir leyendo y escribiendo.

Leer una línea y volcarla en disco tiene el problema de que puede ser muy ineficiente, ya que se hacen muchas llamadas al sistema para escribir poca información, con lo que tu programa se vuelve más lento, especialmente si pasa mucho tiempo entre una llamada a disco y la siguiente.

Sin embargo, puedes leer un bloque de líneas que veas razonable: 500 líneas, 1000 líneas, etc. Algo que veas razonable y que quepa en tu memoria (sin ser un número inmenso). Lees N líneas, las procesas, las almacenas en RAM, y cuando hayas alcanzado el límite lo vuelcas en el fichero.

De esta manera no agotas la memoria de la JVM nunca y no pierdes eficiencia al hacer muchas llamadas al sistema para escribir poca información.

Conceptualmente:

```
List<List<String>> bloqueLineas;
List<String> lineaCsv;
String lineaFichero;

while (hayContenido(fichero)) {
    bloqueLineas = new List<List<String>>();
    do {    // Bucle que lee u bloque de N líneas
        lineaFichero = reader.readLine();
        lineaCsv = lineaFichero.split(",", -1);
        bloqueLineas.add(lineaCsv);
    } while (bloqueLineas.length() < 500 && hayContenido(fichero));

    // Bucle de escritura del bloque leído
    for (List<String> linea : bloqueLineas) {
        for (String campo : linea) {
            writer.write(campo);
            writer.write(";");
        }
        writer.write("\n");
    }
}
```

**Edición:**

Como comenta Ruslan en su respuesta, puedes utilizar *streams*, lo que sería un refinamiento del enfoque que propongo, y que te facilitaría la tarea de leer y volcar poco a poco el fichero.

Sin embargo no te recomiendo leer línea por línea, sino leer un bloque de N líneas, para conseguir un acceso a disco más eficiente, al leer y escribir más información con menos llamadas al sistema, y sobre todo causando menos escrituras físicas en disco (recuerda que los ficheros se mapean a RAM, con lo que varias escrituras juntas en un fichero pueden implicar solo una, o muy pocas, escrituras en disco, si se hacen en un período de tiempo corto y sobre partes contiguas del fichero).

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente tu programa hace lo siguiente en el método main:

```
// 1 se reserva espacio para un apuntador a el flujo de entrada estandard
// 2 se reserva espacio para una lista de listas
// 3 se reserva espacio para la variable i
// 4 se crea un flujo al archivo a leer
// 5 se le pone un buffer y se agrega a la memoria
// 6 se crea un flujo al archivo a escribir
// 7 se le pone un buffer y se agrega a la memoria
// 8 se lee una línea y se almacena
// 9 si la línea existe se almacena en una lista que tiene un arreglo de 13 elementos
// 10 mientras sea posible regrea al paso 8 y si no continua
// 11 recorre la lista de listas para escribir los pedazos de cadena al vuelo
```

El primer inconveniente es que eso no cumple con la S de SOLID pues estás tratando de hacer varias cosas al mismo tiempo.

Divídelo en **dos funciones**, una para **leer el archivo** y una **para escribirlo**, esto de entrada te dará los siguientes beneficios:

- tu flujo para leer el archivo `reader` **se dejará de usar luego de salir** del primer método, liberando precioso espacio en memoria
- no se usará memoria para el proceso de escritura hasta que no inicies el proceso de escritura, lo que hará que durante la lectura tengas un uso más eficiente
- **no mezclarás la lógica** de lectura con escritura, así que será más fácil depurar y mantener tu programa después.

Opcionalmente para tu método de lectura puedes usar otra vez SOLID, y una vez terminando de leer puedes procesar los datos para en vez de tener tu arreglo de arreglos tener **simplemente una cadena lista para escribirse**. En este punto es importante mencionar como es el uso de cadenas en Java, en esencia cada cadena se almacena en memoria prácticamente or siempre por lo que **tener muchas nos crea problemas de uso de memoria**, así que para combatir este problema usaremos la clase `StrigBuilder` y le iremos agregando los datos que queramos y ya hasta el momento que queramos obtener la cadena le llamamos a su método `toString()`.

Eso nos dejaría con un método de escritura que solamente escribe una cadena, así que al llegar a este unto nuestra estructura de datos compleja se habrá eliminado de memoria por ya no usarse más (implicita o explícitamente) y la escriura de una cadena no debería de representar ningún problema.

Finalmente por si no lo pudiste ver entre líneas, el uso de `ArrayList` se puede optimizar si conoces suficienemente bien los datos, como esta estructura de datos está implementada con un arreglo se pierde desempeño y se gasta memoria cada que se sobrepasa el tamaño (13 por defecto y el crecimiento es del doble si no mal recuerdo), así que inicializa tus arraylist p**oniéndoles como parámetro el numero de elementos esperados** de manera que evites que crezca de tamaño inecesariamente, e**sto hará que los picos de uso de memoria desaparezcan** y tengas un uso constante y moderado de ella.

Estas optimizaciones funcionarán para archivos moderadamente grandes, si con ellas no te fuera suficiente deberás de enfocarte en pensar los streams como flujos infinitos de datos e **ir en paralelo leyendo y escribiendo por pedazos**, como por ejemplo línea por línea y de esta manera evitar almacenar mucha información en tus estructuras de datos
y usarlas como un búffer.